# Unable to print the result after submitibg the quiz?

Tags: php

I am trying to use this code, but in result it is not displaying the right answer? it is only displaying your answer is wrong?

```
 <?php  
      session_start();
      require_once 'config.php';
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select question_name,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer from ogt_questions  limit 1'),MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $question_name = $row['question_name'];
    unset($row['question_name']);
    //shuffle($row);
?>
    <form method="POST" action="zQuiz_show_answer.php?q=<?php echo $question_name ?>">
    <p><?php echo $question_name; ?></p>
    <?php
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<input type='radio' name='answe'>".$value."</input></br> ";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
</form>

    <?php

     session_start();
    require_once 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ 
  $answe =  $_POST["answe"];

$ans = mysql_result(mysql_query('select answer2 from ogt_questions where question_name="'.urldecode($_GET['q']).'"'),0);

    if("$answe" == $ans){
        echo "You got it right!";
    }
    else

        echo "You got it wrong! $ans";
} 
?>
```

Comment: why you are starting `session`,`config.php` multiple times in a page

Comment: instead of using mysql_ use mysqli_ or PDO becoz mysql is deprecated now

Comment: Your input has no value. Your SQL is open to injections. You're missing a semicolon when echoing the get parameter for your form action. Why check the answer in PHP, check it with the SQL. You also should urlencode the question since you are decoding it.

Comment: You don't need to call `urldecode()`, that's done automatically when the parameter is put into `$_GET`.

Comment: Your radio buttons don't have any `value` attributes, so nothing will be put in `$_POST["answe"]`.

Answer (score 1):

print $answe variable whether it diplayes selected answer.
And remove double quote check

```
if(trim($answe) == $ans){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if("$answe" == $ans){
```

to

```
if($answe == $ans){
```

Better to have Question ID's numbers

Comment: There's no difference between `$answe` and `"$answe"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something in the `value` attribute of the radio buttons, because that's what gets submitted, not the text of the button. You can use the column name as the value.

```
<?php
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='answe' value='$key'>".$value."</input></br> ";
    }
?>
```

Then when you're checking the answer, you don't need to perform a query. You can just check:

```
if ($answe == "answer2")
```

Although I think this will be a pretty easy quiz if answer2 is the correct answer for all question.